# Android google Map Api V2 Crashes on runtime

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps

I am trying to add a map fragment to an android layout using google map api v2.
I have followed several tutorials, even the one google has and has been pointed by a post here.
My app crashes after starting the layout.
My Files are
Manifest (in [My Key] there is an actual key from Google console using debug code and my package name:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.publicthreadsmap"

    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.publicthreadsmap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.publicthreadsmap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.publicthreadsmap.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                android:value="[my Key]"/>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >


       <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
        android:text="Test" />


     <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/> 




</RelativeLayout>
```

and the Java file :

```
package com.example.publicthreadsmap;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity  {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }



}
```

I have copied (import) the google-play-service-lib in my workspace and referenced it from my map project.
I have also referenced the v4 android support jar.

LogCat massages:
    05-04 10:19:56.284: E/AndroidRuntime(21660): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    05-04 10:19:56.284: E/AndroidRuntime(21660): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.publicthreadsmap/com.example.publicthreadsmap.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class fragment
    05-04 10:19:56.284: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1968)
    05-04 10:19:56.284: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1993)
    05-04 10:19:56.284: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
    05-04 10:19:56.284: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1159)
    05-04 10:19:56.284: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    05-04 10:19:56.284: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    05-04 10:19:56.284: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
    05-04 10:19:56.284: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    05-04 10:19:56.284: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    05-04 10:19:56.284: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:978)
    05-04 10:19:56.284: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)
    05-04 10:19:56.284: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    05-04 10:19:56.284: E/AndroidRuntime(21660): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class fragment
    05-04 10:19:56.284: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
    05-04 10:19:56.284: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
    05-04 10:19:56.284: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
    05-04 10:19:56.284: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
    05-04 10:19:56.284: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
    05-04 10:19:56.284: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:272)
    05-04 10:19:56.284: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
    05-04 10:19:56.284: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at com.example.publicthreadsmap.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
    05-04 10:19:56.284: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4469)
    05-04 10:19:56.284: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1052)
    05-04 10:19:56.284: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1932)
    05-04 10:19:56.284: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    ... 11 more
    05-04 10:19:56.284: E/AndroidRuntime(21660): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that  is in the  element of AndroidManifest.xml
    05-04 10:19:56.284: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at maps.z.ab.a(Unknown Source)
    05-04 10:19:56.284: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at maps.z.ab.a(Unknown Source)
    05-04 10:19:56.284: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at maps.z.ab.a(Unknown Source)
    05-04 10:19:56.284: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at maps.z.ag.a(Unknown Source)
    05-04 10:19:56.284: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at maps.z.ag.a(Unknown Source)
    05-04 10:19:56.284: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at maps.z.bw.a(Unknown Source)
    05-04 10:19:56.284: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at maps.z.r.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
    05-04 10:19:56.284: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$Stub.onTransact(IMapFragmentDelegate.java:107)
    05-04 10:19:56.284: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:297)
    05-04 10:19:56.284: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$a$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
    05-04 10:19:56.284: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
    05-04 10:19:56.284: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.e$4.a(Unknown Source)
    05-04 10:19:56.284: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.e.a(Unknown Source)
    05-04 10:19:56.284: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.e.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
    05-04 10:19:56.284: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
    05-04 10:19:56.284: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1460)
    05-04 10:19:56.284: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:884)
    05-04 10:19:56.284: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1066)
    05-04 10:19:56.284: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1168)
    05-04 10:19:56.284: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:280)
    05-04 10:19:56.284: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:669)
    05-04 10:19:56.284: E/AndroidRuntime(21660):    ... 21 more

Comment: can u post stack trace

Comment: Ok Posted, sorry. If it matters I'm using a galaxy tab GT-P7511 with android 4.0.4 (real device) for testing. Any Ideas could help as I'm new at this.

Comment: error is while inflating layout,can you just give a try by removing `textView1` from your xml for temporary bases?

Comment: Done that. Nothing changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error:

> E/AndroidRuntime(21660): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.publicthreadsmap/com.example.publicthreadsmap.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class fragment

indicates that there was a problem inflating class fragment, this usually happens when `SupportMapFragment` class could not be found. What leads me to think that you did not referenced the `google-play-services` correctly.

please read the first 3 steps of this blog post and make sure you are doing it's correctly, and you have a green V next to the referencing in the properties window:

[Google Map API V2](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

**UPDATE:**

Now I see your problem, change this:

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.publicthreadsmap.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="[my Key]"/>
    </activity>
</application>
```

To this:

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.publicthreadsmap.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="[my Key]"/>     
</application>
```

Look carefully at the location of the last `activity` tag. `meta-data` tag should appear right before the closing `application` tag.

Comment: Thanks for the link.References I think are ok, the green V shows up in my android tag of the properties window.

Comment: Check @Mehul's answer. I missed that line in your stack trace. it looks like you have some problem with your key.

Comment: @EmilAdz : Nice observation,I caught the error from trace but you caught the cause of that trace from manifest.lol

Comment: @MehulJoisar, yeah.. I got an idea that there is something wrong with the key if it can't be found in the Manifest from you answer. This brought me to a conclusion that there is a problem with the way key was provided. +1 for that.

Comment: @EmilAdz:Thanks bro.+1 for going 1 more step forward.

Answer (score 2):

```
E/AndroidRuntime(21660): ... 11 more 05-04 10:19:56.284: E/AndroidRuntime(21660): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found. Check that is in the element of AndroidManifest.xml
```

have a look at [how to get api key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#the_google_maps_api_key)

and remove `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>` from manifest,it is used only while dealing with map api v1 which is deprecated now.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have deleted the line from manifest, didn't work. The api key was obtain following the very same link you posted. I have the debug.keystore string, I have added the ;[package name] and enabled the google android map V2 service.

Comment: @user2347925: You have listed `<meta-data />` inside `<activity />` that is why the compiler wasn't able to find your `api key` and giving error what I have posted in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please delete line

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
```

from Manifest. If you added necessary jars(google play services, sndroid support v4) and modules, it must work.

Comment: Deleted, still the same. Forgot to post the logCat massages:

Comment: If it matters I'm using a galaxy tab GT-P7511 with android 4.0.4. Any Ideas could help as I'm new at this.

Comment: did you configure your galaxy's settings

Comment: edit class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" to class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" and retry.

Comment: you last comment is wrong as the minSDK he is targeting is 8.

Comment: You mentioned something about adding modules(the jars are added), what is that?

Comment: I have tried the mapFragment, didn't work. By setting of my device if you mean usb-debug mode, it is on. Are there any other settings?

Comment: I had same problem, I added required jars but it didn't work. And I added whole google-play-services as module and problem was solved.

Comment: That sounds like something, how do I add a module?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code in manifest file:

```
 <meta-data
 android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
 android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```