# Missing Google API Key in Manifest (Android)

Tags: android, google-maps

I am having trouble getting past the following error, which suggests that I am missing a tag in my manifest:

```
05-04 17:05:16.517: E/AndroidRuntime(26717): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
```

Having read [Google Maps Android API V2 problems with android 4.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21120970/google-maps-android-api-v2-problems-with-android-4-3), and [Android google Map Api V2 Crashes on runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16371811/android-google-map-api-v2-crashes-on-runtime), I still have not had any luck in fixing my issue.

My manifest can be found below:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<permission
    android:name="com.mapgenius.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" >
</permission>

<uses-permission android:name="com.mapgenius.googlemaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.mapgenius.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="MY_KEY" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

Update:

```
 <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="MY_KEY" />
```

should have read:

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="MY_KEY" />
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to obtain a Google Maps API key and put it in your manifest by adding:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="API_KEY"/>
```

It is described in detail on the [Google Developers page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#get_an_android_certificate_and_the_google_maps_api_key).

Comment: Yeah, for some reason I had actually tried this initially, but I suppose another error led me down the wrong path in fixing it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You specified the key with `com.google.android.gms.version`, that needs to be `com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY` instead.

Comment: For which tag should that be applied to? Both?

Comment: You are amazing, thank you. To be clear, I only needed to apply that tag to the first tag..Updating it in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As of Jan 1, 2024, the Google Maps SDK documentation page states:
[image]

Which is kind of confusing. The entry:

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
android:value="${MAPS_API_KEY}" />
```

Only needs to be:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="YOUR_API_KEY" />
```

The $ in the 'value' section doesn't need to be there. In fact, when I tested my app with the $ preceding the API key the map activity showed up blank. Removing the $ allowed the map to render correctly.